# How to have downloads be automatically unblocked?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, security, permissions, group-policy

Downloaded exe files requires me to open the properties of the file and click on "Unblock" because

```
"This file came from another computer and might be
blocked to help protect this computer."
```

Otherwise when running the exe file I get the error message

```
"Windows cannot access the specified device, path,
or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions
to access the item.
```

How do I set downloads to be automatically unblocked? I have admin access... (OS: Windows Server 2003)

---

**Edit** Roy's answer *should* work, so I accepted it. It doesn't work for me with Google Chrome because of [this Chrome bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5719) which currently is still open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **Group Policy** to disable this behavior, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Simply unblock the file by **right-click**ing on it, **Properties**, **General tab** – click on the Unblock button.

> Group Policy:
>   run **gpedit.msc**
>   **User Configuration** > **Administrative Templates** > **Windows Components** > **Attachment Manager**
>   Enable: Do not preserve zone information in file attachments

Comment: this sounds like the perfect solution, thanks. unfortunately, even after setting this (and rebooting), the effect still remains, including for new downloads... I also tried setting the "default risk level" to moderate. still no luck. i must be doing something wrong still...any thoughts?

Comment: figured out why (using Google Chrome): http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5719

So thanks! I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Just tested in latest Chrome. Looks to be fixed :)

Comment: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments]
"SaveZoneInformation"=dword:00000001

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the "Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration" from Add/Remove Windows Components.

Log out, log back in, and you should be good to go.

If there's a more secure means of doing this (I really don't like doing it this way), please let me know.